# Intel Fortran: write multi-item namelist to internal file?

Tags: fortran

I want to write a namelist with multiple items (hence multiple lines) to a character variable. The following code runs well when compiled with gfortran, but returns a write error when compiled with ifort:

```
program test
  implicit none
  type testtype
     real*8 :: x
     character(len=32) :: str
     logical :: tf
  end type testtype
  type(testtype) :: thetype
  integer :: iostat
  character(len=1000) :: mystr(10)
  namelist /THENAMELIST/ thetype
  integer :: i

  thetype%x = 1.0d0
  thetype%str="This is a string."
  thetype%tf = .true.

  mystr=""
  write(*,nml=THENAMELIST,delim="QUOTE")
  write(mystr,THENAMELIST,iostat=iostat,delim="QUOTE")
  write(*,*)"Iostat:",iostat

  do i = 1, size(mystr)
     write(*,*)i,trim(mystr(i))
  end do

end program test
```

The output is the following:

```
> ifort -o test test.f90 ; ./test
 &THENAMELIST
 THETYPE%X       =   1.00000000000000     ,
 THETYPE%STR     = "This is a string.               ",
 THETYPE%TF      = T
 /
 Iostat:          66
           1 &THENAMELIST THETYPE%X=   1.00000000000000     ,
           2 
           3 
           4 
           5 
           6 
           7 
           8 
           9 
          10
```

Intel's list of run-time error messages tells me: "severe (66): Output statement overflows record".

For over completeness, using gfortran I of course get

```
> gfortran -o test test.f90 ; ./test
&THENAMELIST
 THETYPE%X=  1.0000000000000000     ,
 THETYPE%STR="This is a string.               ",
 THETYPE%TF=T,
 /
 Iostat:           0
           1 &THENAMELIST
           2  THETYPE%X=  1.0000000000000000     ,
           3  THETYPE%STR="This is a string.               ",
           4  THETYPE%TF=T,
           5  /
           6 
           7 
           8 
           9 
          10
```

I have searched all over the internet, and learned that the internal file cannot be a scalar character variable, but that's about as much as I found. GFortran does accept a scalar variable and just writes newlines in that variable, but that, I guess, is non-standard fortran.

The compilers I used are:

- gfortran GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc48 4.8-20130411_0) 4.8.1 20130411 (prerelease)
- ifort (IFORT) 12.0.5 20110719 (on mac)
- ifort (IFORT) 13.1.1 20130313 (on GNU/Linux)

My question is: what is the error in my syntax, or how else can I write a namelist to an internal file, without having to patch the problem by writing to an actual external scratch file and read that into my variable (which is what I do now, but which is slow for large namelists)?

Comment: i suspect the answer is internal namelist writing is not defined by the standard and so hit or miss what compilers choose to do with it.

Comment: I second @george's comment.  The Intel Fortran User Guide states (p200 of Intel document 304970-006US) that namelist formatting is not supported for writing to internal files and I believe that the standard does not require that such support be implemented.  As for namelist formatting for derived types ...

Comment: Thanks for your comments! So it is non-standard, and I have to stick with the output to a scratch file, which I could then read back into a character array if I wish. So my problem is "solved".

Comment: Actually, I found [this link at IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101l.doc%2Fxlflr%2Fnamelistio.htm) saying that a namelist to an internal file is Fortran2003 standard. So I guess that in a future iteration of ifort it will be included.